# What does “another” mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

If someone says “Tom broke another lamp,” does it imply that Tom already broke a lamp or that another lamp was previously broken by someone?

Comment: There is not enough context to answer your question.

Comment: This is an interesting question that shows the importance of context in interpreting what seems to be a straightforward sentence.

Comment: Yes. Tom broke another lamp **or** another lamp was broken.

Comment: I don't think ELU would have a bright future if we started welcoming questions of the general form *"What does [some ambiguous construction] mean?"*. The reality is that *every* word, clause, or statement can have multiple meanings. I really see little point in questions where every answer would have to start with *"The meaning depends on context"* - if the user can't or won't supply enough context to at least *potentially* admit of a *single, unambiguously correct answer*, the question should be closed, not answered.

Comment: Sigh. Use the voting buttons folks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wasn't aware that this site was exclusively for asking questions with "a _single, unambiguously correct answer_". If you have to have that level of quality control over questions before asking them, then you likely have the resources to answer your own question, which would then make the site evaporate into nothingness. Not everything in life has a clear answer.

Comment: @Rich: The text on our Help pages gets amended fairly often, but it wouldn't surprise me in the least if I actually cut&pasted *single, unambiguously correct answer* from there 18 months ago. Certainly the *principle* still applies. I'm not sure if medica's *This is an interesting question* is supposed to imply she approves of it being posed here, but my impression is every time the Help pages get updated, they stress more and more strongly the importance of providing *full context*. Otherwise we'd just end up dealing with questions like *What does "that" mean?*

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the context, it could mean either.

> It looked like Tom finally had his clumsiness under control, but no. Tom broke another lamp.

Here it’s implied that Tom has broken lamps before (and perhaps other things too).

> Dick and Harriet ran through the corridors, smashing light fixtures. Tom broke another lamp.

Here it’s clear that Tom is just one of several people breaking lights.

---

As Oldcat noted in a comment, *another* might even mean “different” instead of “additional”:

> Tom didn’t break the lamp in the hall. Tom broke another lamp.

Comment: It could also mean that one light fixture in total was broken by Tom.  But the one he broke was different from that named. *"Did Tom break the lamp in the hall?"*  No, Tom broke another lamp.

Comment: @Oldcat Thank you for the excellent observation! I've incorporated it into the answer.